# jQuery replace text between parentheses

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a requirement to replace the text between () in a string.

Answer (score 21):

```
"string()".replace(/\(.*?\)/, "replacement")
```

Comment: FYI: This solution includes the parentheses in the replacement.  Which is not exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a regex - this isn't jQuery, but a part of JavaScript:

```
var s = "hello (there)";
s = s.replace(/\(.*?\)/, 'world');
```

For more than a single pair:

```
s = s.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, 'world');
```

This will not work if the parentheses contain more parentheses, mind you; another option is to use `/\(.*\)/` to capture from first to last - `"a (b (c) d)"` --> `"a world"`, but the same for  `"a (b) c (d)"`.

Comment: FYI: This solution includes the parentheses in the replacement.  Which is not exactly what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using JQuery, use regular expressions: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

It's the second example, where you can specify a regex to target the ( and ), and then replace the inner contents...  something like /(.+)/i as a regular expression should work.

HTH.

Comment: You don't need `/i` there, parentheses don't have upper and lower cases - this is only useful when matching literals.

Comment: For future reference: this solution replaces text BETWEEN the parentheses.  Solutions below by Kobi and Koctehko replace the text between the parenthasees and also the parenthasees themselves.